It is good of you to eat/be eating with us
To express gratitude to someone who is eating with my family right now, which one would I say?

It is good of you to eat with us.

It is good of you to be eating with us.


What if they've finished eating or not started yet? Could I say:
It is good of you to eat with us.

No, it was good of you to have dinner with us. eat with us is a bit crude in that sentence. The present is happening. As we sit at the table, I'd say: It's good of you to have lunch with us.

Shouldn't the person who is being given a meal be the one expressing gratitude, or don't the normal conventions of etiquette apply in this situation?

If you invite an important person to your home, you can feel honored if they accept the invitation.  In English-speaking countries we would say something like  "We're honored to have you as our guest."   But if there is no honor involved, and you are simply happy they accepted your invitation, "We're delighted you could come."

One of the confusing things here is how English uses infinitives ("to eat") and "-ing verbs" ("eating") similarly. E.g. "I like to eat" and "I like eating" are pretty much the same. Now, present progressive ("to be eating") is different and has a different meaning; it literally means action is happening right now.
There's no reason, even when action is happening right now, that we have to use present progressive. I could be riding a horse and say "I like to ride." Or I could use it if I wanted to: "I'm so glad to be riding today." Some ideas are more tied "to the moment," and some are less so. Your examples using "It is good of you" are value statements, evaluations of a person's merit. Even before you start eating or long after you finish, the "goodness" of the person for coming to the meal will remain true. Because of this, progressive tense isn't very idiomatic for this choice.
